# Unmet dependencies Pipelight

Tags: apt, dependencies, pipelight

I am trying to install pipelight onto my notebook.

Sadly I can't manage to get it installed.
Every try to install it ends up with:
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
pipelight-multi : Depends: wine-staging
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I have spent several hours in the internet, really tried everything to get this fixed - still nothing seemed to work.

I would post my sources-list and sources-list-d, but this results in an error on this page, since my post would contain more than 1 link then.

As just said, I really tried nearly everything.

Stuff like:

```
sudo apt-get -f install
```

Results in:

```
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgrade
```

Is there anything I can do to fix this issue?
Clearing apt-cache doesn't work, doing dist-upgrades, purging the PPAs..
Nearly visited every single result in google on the first two pages, tried everything - still can't get this to work.

Thanks!

Comment: did you follow this thread http://askubuntu.com/questions/140246/how-do-i-resolve-unmet-dependencies

Comment: Yes. I worked through all of that. When using dist-upgrade, I ran into a problem.
I had to remove very old kernel versions afterwards.
After removing the old kernel-versions, everything like "apt-get -f install" results in "0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgrade"

Comment: use the following: `sudo apt-get remove --purge pipelight-multi wine-staging` then install `sudo apt-get install pipelight-multi wine-staging` if that doesn't help you have to disable PPAs as instructed in my first comment usually cause of them it happens.

Comment: [Edit] your question and add the output of `apt-cache policy pipelight-multi` and give me a ping with @A.B.

Comment: You should be able to post your sources list if you wrap it in code tags -- either indent every line with four spaces (tab won't work), or put a back-tick (on a standard 102-key, this is the key left of number 1) before and after the `code` text.

Answer (score 0):

If you run one of this Ubuntu versions

- Ubuntu 15.10
- Ubuntu 15.04
- Ubuntu 14.10
- Ubuntu 14.04
- Ubuntu 12.04

than follow the steps below

1. Remove the package `pipelight-multi`

   ```
   sudo apt-get purge pipelight-multi
   ```
2. Add the PPA `ppa:pipelight/stable`

   ```
   sudo apt-add-repository ppa:pipelight/stable
   ```
3. Update the package information

   ```
   sudo apt-get update
   ```
4. Install pipelight

   ```
   sudo apt-get install pipelight-multi
   ```

Comment: This happens to me even with the PPA on 15.04

Comment: @Goddard works in my Vivid system. :\

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same problem in Ubuntu 15.10.
The following command fixed the issue for me:

```
sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386
```

Just in case, here are all commands i ran in chronological order:

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:pipelight/stable
sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install --install-recommends pipelight-multi
```

Answer (score 0):

Although this question is old, I thought I'd add some useful info for anything after 15.10, but also for the original question.
It seems after 16.04 there is no more pipelight build, so after that it's possible to take the deb from here and make sure the dependencies are met:

https://launchpad.net/~pipelight/+archive/ubuntu/stable/+build/9708266

To meet the dependency wine-staging , one can use the WineHQ PPA as described [here](https://wiki.winehq.org/Ubuntu):

```
sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386 
wget -qO- https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/winehq.key | sudo apt-key add -
sudo apt-add-repository 'deb http://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu/ bionic main'
```

(replace bionic by any other name for your version if that's older, or upgrade to latest LTS)

then:

```
sudo apt install wine-staging
```

then from the folder with your downloaded deb:

```
sudo dpkg -i pipelight-multi_0.2.8.2_ubuntu16.04.1_amd64.deb
```

(might need `sudo apt --fix-broken install` afterwords if terminal feedback shows that).
Mind the terminal output that says to activate the license with:

```
touch $HOME/.config/wine-wininet-installer.accept-license
```

Installing wine as described should give you what you need and answer this question.
I hope that helps you. You may need an older firefox version to get the plugin working (before Firefox 52).